# I'm making a code with pygame in oop and I'm having trouble making one of my methods work

Tags: oop, methods, pygame

Basically, I am making a code that uses oop and pygame together. It draws 4 rectangles in the corners of the screen and gives each rectangle a name. I have to ask the user the name of one of the rectangles and change that rectangles color randomly.

Code:

```py
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("BOOGABOOGA")
blue = (0,0,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
white = (255,255,255)
random = [blue,red,green,white]
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self,name,color,x,y,width,height,thickness):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.thickness = thickness
    def coolboymethoddraw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),self.thickness)
        
recty1 = Rectangle("YOYO",blue,50,50,50,50,0)
recty2 = Rectangle("BABYBOOGA",blue,450,450,50,50,0)
recty3 = Rectangle("ChotaBEAM",blue,0,450,50,50,0)
recty4 = Rectangle("CHOTAJAGGU",blue,450,0,50,50,0)
jaggu = [recty1,recty2,recty3,recty4]
recty3.coolboymethoddraw()
recty1.coolboymethoddraw()
recty4.coolboymethoddraw()
recty2.coolboymethoddraw()
def change_color(self):
    print("Give me the name of 1 of the 4 rectangles!")
    x = input()
    for chota in jaggu:
        if  x == chota.name:
            l = random.choice(random)
            chota.color = l
recty1.change_color()
recty2.changecolor()
recty3.change_color()
recty4.change_color()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

I would appreciate an answer and why it wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: what exactly is not working? first of you need to move `change_color` to be an instance method, so put it inside the class definition, also you have incorrectly used its name in one case

Answer (score 0):

First of all move your method change_color inside the class Rectangle.

```
class Rectangle:
def __init__(self,name,color,x,y,width,height,thickness):
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.thickness = thickness
def coolboymethoddraw(self):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.color,(self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height),self.thickness)
def change_color(self):
    print("Give me the name of 1 of the 4 rectangles!")
    x = input()
    for chota in jaggu:
        if  x == chota.name:
            l = random.choice(random)
            chota.color = l
```

Then you need to move the draw methods inside the main loop, otherwise the rectangles will not be drawn.

```
while True:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        exit()
recty3.coolboymethoddraw()
recty1.coolboymethoddraw()
recty4.coolboymethoddraw()
recty2.coolboymethoddraw()
pygame.display.update()
```

Dont name your list of colors random because you import a package called random. Name the list something like colors_list

You dont need to call the change_color method for all 4 rectangles because inside of this method you go through a list of your 4 rectangles already.

There is also a problem in the change_color method. You need to call the method inside the main loop as well, but because of the print statement and the input it will end in an ifinite loop.